# Investigating Java JIT Other Memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, jit

I am investigating out of memory issues with a java application running in a docker container orchestrated by mesos marathon.

- the container is set to 2GB memory
- JVM heap is explicitly set to 1Gb min and 1.5GB max
- constant test workload and then eventual container exit code 137 (OOM).
- compared two javacores at beginning of the test and after 1 hour, noticed something called  JIT "Other" has the most delta
- no issues are seen with JVM heap usage

Initial

```
2MEMUSER      +--JIT: 318,789,520 bytes / 778 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Code Cache: 268,435,456 bytes / 1 allocation
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Data Cache: 16,777,728 bytes / 8 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 33,576,336 bytes / 769 allocations
```

After 1 hour

```
2MEMUSER      +--JIT: 525,843,728 bytes / 8046 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Code Cache: 268,435,456 bytes / 1 allocation
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Data Cache: 62,916,480 bytes / 30 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 194,491,792 bytes / 8015 allocations
```

I wanted to know if a core dump with the Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) might shed light on what is in this "Other" space.

We have tried to limit JIT memory usage by following [this discussion](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/375916/how-to-set-the-jit-code-cache-reserved-memory-in-w.html)

```
*-Xjit:disableCodeCacheConsolidation
-Xcodecachetotal128m*
```

but can't seem to get the args to work.

We are using 
IBM JRE  1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 (build 8.0.5.17 - pxa6480sr5fp17-20180627_01(SR5 FP17))

Can people please share tools/experience troubleshooting JIT native memory consumption?

Comment: Did you find the solution eventually? I am having same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a memory leak in "metaspace" memory.  This is off-heap memory that is used by the JVM to hold (for example) JIT-compiled classes and other class metadata.

A couple of common causes of metaspace leaks are:

- classloader leaks resulting from repeated hot-loading of code during development, or
- leaks of `Proxy` classes / objects or similar.

There are JVM options that can limit the size of metaspace; e.g. `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m`.

---

Here's a Q&A on diagnosing metaspace leaks:

- [How to diagnose a Java 8 metaspace leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423390/how-to-diagnose-a-java-8-metaspace-leak)

---

I just noticed that you are using an IBM JRE rather than an Oracle / OpenJDK one.  So the above is not directly applicable.

The root problem could well be the same though: leakage via classloaders / hot-loading or via Proxy classes.